# WPF: Make ListViewItem ToolTip follow mouse (MouseMove)

Tags: wpf, tooltip, listviewitem, mousemove

I've found [a solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e379ebe7-8dc1-4aad-b832-60e00c21ef8f/how-make-a-tooltip-follow-the-mousepointer) for having a tooltip follow the cursor / mouse.

This works very well for me.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to apply this method to a ListViewItem.  Here is an example of one of my listview's XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvBoxes" FontSize="9" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="125" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                SelectionChanged="lvBoxes_SelectionChanged" 
                MouseLeftButtonUp="lvBoxes_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="lvBoxesItem_MouseMove" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Verified}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Boxnum}" Header="BOX#" Width="50" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Qty}" Header="QTY" Width="50" />
            </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

I've tried adding `<Setter x:Name="ttBox" Property="ToolTip" Value="A Tooltip" />` to the `<Style>`, but I'm unable to reference (in this example) `ttBox` in the code behind.

Comment: There is no dev environment on my hands, so I can only give your some tips.First,you should define ItemDataTemplate for listview, create your "Button", in mousemove handler,the sender parameter will help you to find tooltip control((sender as button).ToolTip), then you can set the position of it.

Comment: It's not a `Button` but a `ListViewItem` that I wanted this for.  However, you're on the right track, and you have my thanks for taking the time to comment.  See my answer below (which I wasn't able to post until today.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion I originally linked to had me trying to access the `ListViewItem.ToolTip` in code behind as follows (assuming I had included `<Setter x:Name="ttBox" Property="ToolTip" Value="A Tooltip" />` in my originally posted XAML `<style>` section):

```
private void lvBoxesItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ttBox.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;
    ttBox.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + 10;
    ttBox.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y + 10;    
}
```

I've found that while I wasn't able to access the `ToolTip` by x:Name in code behind, I was able to modify my code behind as follows to achieve the effect I was looking for (this requires that you don't set the `ToolTip` property in XAML):

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip(); // Initialized with the Window

private void lvBoxesItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvItem = sender as ListViewItem;
    lvItem.ToolTip = tt;
    tt.Content = "Sample ToolTip Text";
    tt.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;
    tt.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + 10;
    tt.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y + 10;    
}
```

I should note, however, that this is only effective if you don't need/want to bind data directly to your `ToolTip`, which, in my case, isn't necessary.